# bread crumb arg()

Tags: theming, webforms

I want to write code to translate the breadcrumb I use.

```
function MYTHEM_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  $breadcrumb[] = drupal_get_title();
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    $type = $node->type;
    if ($type) {
      switch ($type) {
         case 'event':
          $breadcrumb['breadcrumb']= l(t('Event'), 'event');
          break;
         case 'news':
          $breadcrumb['breadcrumb']= l(t('News'), 'news');
          break;
/****This error from here*** */
         case 'webform': 
         if (arg(0)== 'node' && arg(1) == 263 && arg(2) == 'done') {
             $breadcrumb['breadcrumb'] = t('Attend an Event');
            }
           $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' > ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
           return $output;
         break;
      }
  }
    $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' > ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
    return $output;
  }
}
```

It did not execute the `if (arg(0)== 'node' && arg(1) == 263 && arg(2) == 'done')` part.
The URL I am accessing is MYURL/MYPROJECT/ar/node/7/done?sid=59.

Why doesn't it see the `arg(2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Although this code seems the wrong way to go, i would suggest checking for sid if this is the point anyway (meaning you only want the submitted url)...

```
if(isset($_GET['sid'])
```

or you could break down the $_GET['q'] to explode your validator from the url

```
$url = $_GET['q'];
$fragment = explode('/', $url) and check for $fragment[3]=='done' or any fragment of the $url
```